# Переписать код с Jquery на Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как перевести код с jQuery на javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var imgHeight = $('.gk-zinimage img').height();
    $('.gk-zincontent img').load(function() { // размер картинки после загрезки
        $('.gk-zincontent').css({'height': imgHeight * <?php echo $galereyarows?> + 6 }); // высота div по размеру картинки
        $('.gk-articles-mainwrap, .gk-articles').css({'height': imgHeight * <?php echo $galereyarows?> + 6, 'overflow': 'hidden'}); // 'overflow': 'hidden' скрыли лишнее
        return false;
    });
    jQuery('ul.subcats-selection li a').click(function(){
        $('.gk-zinimage').css({'height': imgHeight + 6});
        $('.gk-articles-mainwrap, .gk-articles').css({'height': imgHeight * <?php echo $galereyarows?> + 6, 'overflow': 'hidden'});
    });
});
```

Comment: А в чём именно проблема у вас??? Это же не с  java на php переводить. Если в интернете по отдельности каждое действие вбивать, добавляя "аналог на js", то думаю в вопросах у вас останется максимум 1-2 строчки

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var img = document.querySelector('.gk-zinimage img');
    var imgHeight = img.height;

    img.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var items = document.querySelectorAll('.gk-zincontent');
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            items[i].style.height = imgHeight * <?php echo $galereyarows?> + 6;
        }
        items = document.querySelectorAll('.gk-articles-mainwrap, .gk-articles');
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            items[i].style.height = imgHeight * <?php echo $galereyarows?> + 6;
            items[i].style.overflow = 'hidden';
        }
    });

    var links = document.querySelectorAll('ul.subcats-selection li a');
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        links[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            img.style.height = imgHeight + 6;
            var items = document.querySelectorAll('.gk-articles-mainwrap, .gk-articles');
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                items[i].style.height = imgHeight * <?php echo $galereyarows?> + 6;
                items[i].style.overflow = 'hidden';
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Хотя в этом коде наверняка многое можно оптимизировать.

Comment: Спасибо Дело в том что код на jQuery работает в firefox но в опере нет и в edge тоже нет потому и думаю что на чистом javascript может будет работать

Comment: @Сергей хоть я и не фанат жуквери 99%, что проблема не в нем

Comment: @Сергей обычно наоборот решения на jQuery переносимее ванильного JS.

Comment: Вообще суть была такая. Берется размер картинки и по ее размеру  делается разбивка в блоке. в firefox все отобразилось корректно но в опере jQuery не читается

Comment: @Сергей надо запускать отладчик под Оперой и смотреть, что происходит и почему.

Comment: отладчик под Оперой пишет == $0

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev Спасибо разобрался